# Problem rendering a Django form field with different representation

Tags: django, django-forms

I've implemented a custom form field for percentages (a modified version of [Djangosnippet #1914](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1914/)). I'm doing this like everybody else in the world: Displaying a value of 0.25 as 25%. In order to achieve this we need to multiply the value by 100 before we display it and divide it by 100 when we save it (see below).

The save-part (`clean`) works fine but the problem is with displaying the value (`render` or rather `prepare_value`). There are different types of values that get passed to `prepare_value`. It could be your default (mine is 0) so it would be an *int* but it could also be a *Decimal* (most of the time) because after all it's a *DecimalField*.

The problem arises when the form throws an error and values need to be redisplayed. In this case the form value will be passed to it - which is a *unicode*. So we don't need to multiply the value by 100 as this has been done before (To be more precise: Since the value can be something different than a *Decimal* - namely an *int* or a *unicode* - we need to multiply it only when it's not a *Decimal*. That is - a *DecimalField*). As you can see I've got an ugly workaround using `isinstance` for that.

I'm beginning to think that I really don't understand what's happening here and I've no idea how I can fix this properly. Any suggestions?

```
class PercentInput(TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
        return super(PercentInput, self).render(name, value, attrs) + \
               mark_safe(u' %')


class PercentField(DecimalField):
    widget = PercentInput(attrs={'size': 4, 'maxlength': 5})

    default_error_messages = {
        'positive': _(u'Must be a positive number.'),
    }

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Decimal):
            value *= 100
        return super(PercentField, self).prepare_value(value)

    def clean(self, value):
        value = super(PercentField, self).clean(value)
        if value is None:
            return None
        if value < 0:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['positive'])
        return Decimal('%.4f' % (value / 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a MultiValueField combined with a MultiWidget. The advantage that will give you is that the MultiValueField has a compress method, which you could leverage to take your input and convert it into decimal form, and the MultiWidget has a decompress method to take that decimal and convert it into a string and display it how you want.

I wrote a [Feet and Inches widget](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2327/) that converts a decimal into feet, inches and fractional inches (10' 3 1/2" which is stored in the database as 123.5), which does almost what you want. Hope that helps you out!

Comment: I'm still "stuck" with the code above. After all it works as expected. The Multi-solution you proposed might work - but it feels a bit "heavy" for my little problem. (It's no MultiValueField after all.)